# How can I center this line in the after section? - CSS

Tags: html, css

I want this line to be placed in the middle under the title, but it doesn't work when I try text-align.

```
body {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: 'Noto Sans KR', sans-serif;
}

.title{
    position: relative;
    top: 70px;
    line-height: 15px;
    letter-spacing: 1em;
    font-size: 30px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}

.title::after {
    display: block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 20px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #FFF;
    content: "";
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emA4u.png)

I'm sorry in advance because it's not the time for me to click on the recommendation yet. Thank you for all your answers.

Comment: Since you have used border to show the line under the title, it only gives you border for the block and AFIK you cannot align a border position. So use hr tag and align according to your needs.

Add your HTML and css as a snippet to offer more help!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Will this do?

```css
body {
    background-color: #000;
}

section {
  position:relative;
}

.title{
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 15px;
    letter-spacing: 1em;
    font-size: 30px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom-width: 50%;
}

.title::after {
  position:absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 20px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #FFF;
  content: "";
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  left: 25%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section>
    <div class="title">What I Play</title>
  </section>
</body>
```

Comment: Please, accept answer if solves your issue.

Answer (score -1):

`text-align: center` aligns the inline content of that element, not the element itself.

you probably want to use `margin: 0 auto;` for `.title::after`.

Comment: very thx!!! I used 'margin : auto 0' earlier, but the order was wrong!!

Comment: `margin: auto 0` will not work for borders, it works on the block element

Comment: I must have designated the element as a block! thx!! Purushothaman!!!

Comment: @이현도 `margin: 0 auto` is equivalent to `margin: 0 auto 0 auto`, starting with the top margin and going clockwise (top right bottom left). That sets no vertical margins, and `auto` sets the margin to whatever it takes to fill the container, spread equally on left and right. That's why it horizontally centers the element.

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution to your issue. you have to change small changes in your CSS and also you have to add some css in `.title-box` class.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
<style>
  body {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: 'Noto Sans KR', sans-serif;
}
.title-box{
  text-align:center;
}
.title{
    line-height: 15px;
    letter-spacing: 1em;
    font-size: 30px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.title::after {
    display: flex;
    width: 300px;
    height: 20px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #FFF;
    content: "";
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 10%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container"> 
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 title-box">
          <h1 class="title">What I Play</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `center` tag is deprecated, it shouldn't be used

Comment: you can see. i remove the center tag and add new CSS is following: .title-box{
      text-align:center;
    }